# principiante en ajax: no hace las consultas respectivas en servidor

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Saludos a todos en esta comunidad me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto en el que se genera una lista de compra, esta lista se hace en una tabla y el codigo de productos y cantidades se almacenan en un array conteniendo los 2 array, luego los envio por POST a traves de ajax con un json. hasta ahi todo bien hasta devuelve un mensaje en la funcion "success"

```
var productos=new Array();
var cantidades=new Array();
var combinado= new Array(2);

combinado[0]=productos;
combinado[1]=cantidades;

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(combinado);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ingrcomp2.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert("OK");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }       
});
```

Este es el codigo del servidor (ingrcomp2.php):

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['data']);
$fecha_compra=date("Y-m-d");
$hora=new DateTime();
$hora->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Bogota'));
$hora=$hora->format('H:i:s');
$usuario=$_REQUEST['sel_usuario'];

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sima") or die("Problemas en la conexion a la Base de Datos SIMA");
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
    $compra=$array[1][i];
    $producto=$array[0][i];
```

Luego de esto siguen varias consultas que se hacen en base a la compra y producto. ¿Estoy recorriendo mal el array? ¿Estoy asignando mal?  ¿Estoy usando de forma correcta ajax?. Gracias por su tiempo

Comment: en lugar de **alert("OK")**, te recomiendo utilizar **console.log("OK")** y que actives las **herramientas para desarrolladores** (en el caso de Chrome) y en la pestaña console veas dichos mensajes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dices que sale un mensaje en la función `success`. Pero no veo que hagas nada con los valores retornados de la llamada [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). En la función `success` debes agregar el parámetro que envolverá la respuesta del servidor.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ingrcomp2.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(respuesta){
        console.log(respuesta);
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    }       
});
```

Comment: primero que todo si me sirvio, ahora si puedo ver el error en el servidor pero como se podria mostrar en un alert?

Comment: `alert(respuesta);` Aunque esto solo te mostrará algo así como "Object". Te sugiero que uses un depurador de javascript, por ejemplo [firebug]

Comment: En [Firebug][1], podrás ver que es exactamente lo que te retorna el servidor a través de `console.log(respuesta);`

Comment: pues el console.log me sirvio mucho pero ahora no se porque todas las consultas me retornan "cannot add or update a child row" algo me dice que estoy indicando mal la posicion del array en php...

Comment: Eso es un problema que tienes exactamente en la query que ejecutas en la base de datos. Debes reformular tu pregunta, o bien debes hacer una nueva, ya que tu pregunta inicial es acerca de ajax.

Comment: no hay problema, lo resolvi... era simplemente que en el for no le estaba indicando bien el tamaño del array bidimensional :)